# How to use Firestore's document as unique username?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In order to use Firestore's document as userID(username), I found this way.

```
-> users
    -> UID
        -> name
        -> phone
        -> email

-> usersByName
    -> UserName: UID
```

However, one Google Firestore worker replied me like this on twitter.

[His reply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJ2Ni.png)

I know that each document is unique.
But it will be overwritten by everyone.

> If the document does not exist, it will be created. If the document does exist, its contents will be overwritten with the newly provided data
>   https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data?hl=ja

I want to know what the best way to use document as userID(username) is.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to use a document as a userID(username) when the userID (uid) already exists?

Comment: I would like to make it like twitter and instagram.

Comment: That's pretty unclear. Both of those have users and each user has a user id (i.e. account id) associated with it. Can you clarify the question?

Comment: I would like to let users set their original ID by themselves when they register. But now in my App, the ID is automatically generated by Firebase Auth.

Comment: Correct. That id is a unique identifier for each user. If you want to store additional information about the user such as a display name, favorite food or gender, you would have a node with the users UID as the key, and then children that store additional information */uid_0/display_name: "Batman"* and */uid_0/fav_food: "Caviar"* etc. From there, if you need to keep a reference to that user, simply use their uid:  */posts/created_by/uid_0*

Comment: Thank you very much! I understood!

Comment: @Jay In this constellation, how would you look up user `Jay`? You have to make sure that there is only one user `@Jay` to be able to reliably identify them.

Comment: @TimarIvoBatis If you read through the comments, we are avoiding referencing users by their name because of just that - there could be a lot of Jay's. The preferred method it to reference the user by their guaranteed unique uid in all cases. The other benefit is that if you always use their used id (uid) then you can directly access their info without a query at all. e.g. the users data you want to know about is always located at *users/uid*. So a friends list would be composed of uid's, not names, for example.

Comment: I understood. But that's what OP, referencing twitter and instagram would like to have. A humanly readable UID.
Thanks for the quick response. I'm researching this right now will update. I hope security rules V2 allow for this.

Comment: @TimarIvoBatis That's my point. Never use anything as a documentId (a key) that could be duplicated, as it will overwrite the existing document. Having a humanly readable uid is not relevant - the data stored *within* they document IS relevant. If you look at the structure in the question, the `usersByName` collection is not needed as that data can easily be retrieved by the `users` node, or, if you need to denormalize ,store the users uid's in a separate array that determines an order.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer below:
I added a second check to make sure the `uid` being stored matches the `uid` of the user requesting it.

```
match /usernames/{username} {
   allow create: if !exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/usernames/$(username)) && request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.uid;
}
```

*one more check would be necessary to prevent a single user to register multiple usernames.

Source:
[Enforcing unique userIds in Firebase Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47298750/enforcing-unique-userids-in-firebase-firestore)

Comment: I guess you could do this but why have an entirely separate node of usernames? That's a lot of additional storage, writes and reads driving up costs. What about a simple query on the users collection to see if the username already exists and if not, allow it to be used?

Comment: This could replace the `users` collection completely. But at least you have options now.